# Kivy moving label inside FloatLayout

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Hello I want to place a welcome message at the top of the app (Like the photo [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Nm7a.png))

I use a FloatLayout for my entire screen (since I want to add some other widgets later) but the problem is the label won't position itself at the center but like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MN7Si.png)

Here is my python code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
class MainPage(FloatLayout):
    pass

class SmartMirrorApp(App):
    def build(self, **kwargs):
        return MainPage()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    SmartMirrorApp().run()
```

And this is my kv file:

```
#:kivy 1.10.1

<MainPage>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1,0,1,0.5
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    Label:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: 1,0,0,0.5
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        text: "Welcome, you look beautiful today!"
        font_size: 20
        size_hint: None, None
        size: self.texture_size
        pos_hint: {'x': 0.5, 'y': 0.9}
```

Now if instead of putting 'x':0.5 inside the pos_hint dictionary I use `center_x: root.center_x`
the image moves to the desired position ONLY if I resize the window but it starts at the position of the second image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your `pos_hint`, use:

```
pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'top': 0.9}
```

That will center the `Label` horizontally, and the `top` of the `Label` will be at 90% of the `MainPage` height.